# Task stops working on different environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, task

I'm having hard time with this one.

So in my asp.net application there is such a method:

```
public CopyResponse thirdStage(CopyRequest request)
{
    CopyCCResponse response = new CopyCCResponse();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        performCopying(request);
    });

    return response;
}

private void performCopying(CopyCCRequest request)
{
    using (Repository = new myDbContext())
    {
        // do some initial action
        try
        {
        // in general it looks like below
            foreach(var children in father)
            {
                var newChildren = chldren.Copy();
                Repository.Childrens.Add(newChildren);

                foreach (var grandchldren in children.grandchildrens)
                {
                    var newGrandchildren = grandchldren.Copy();
                    newGrandchildren.Parent = newChildren;

                    Repository.Grandchildrens.Add(newGrandchildren);
                }

                Repository.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log that action failed

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

This method and all other (there are some similar) works as designed on my local computer without any problems.

Unfortunately, on another environment those methods fail:

- Copying smaller parts of data works fine. But when there is over 3000 objects to operate on, method fails.
- Main application is responding correctly nevertheless.
- Most of the operation is done well (most data is copied and saved in database)
- Application doesn't enter catch block. Instructions for failed copying are not executed. Exception isn't caught by the error handler (BTW, I know by default the app can't catch exceptions from independent task, I wrote my handler so it will manage to do so).
- IIS worker process seems to take over 300MB and 0% of processor power after copying stopped. More than half of RAM on server is still free.
- I looked into windows event log, but haven't found anything.

Do you have any suggestions how I can handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do reliable "Fire and forget" tasks from inside IIS, if the site is not being served the application pool will get its `AppDomain` shut down after a while.

Two options to use are:

[`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx) to tell IIS you are doing background work. This will let the server know of the work and it will delay the shutdown as long as it can (default up to 90 seconds max) before it kills your process.

```
public CopyResponse thirdStage(CopyRequest request)
{
    CopyCCResponse response = new CopyCCResponse();

    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(() =>
    {
        performCopying(request);
    });

    return response;
}
```

Another option is to use a 3rd party library that is designed for doing background work in IIS like [Hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/), this will run a service inside of IIS that does the work and attempts to keep the instance alive till the work is done. You can also configure Hangfire to run as a separate process so you don't need to rely on the lifetime of the IIS instance.

```
public CopyResponse thirdStage(CopyRequest request)
{
    CopyCCResponse response = new CopyCCResponse();

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() =>
    {
        performCopying(request);
    });

    return response;
}
```

Note, using hangfire with a seperate process may require you to do a little redesign of `performCopying(CopyCCRequest request)` to support being run from a separate process, using it from inside the IIS instance should not require any changes.

Comment: Thank for your answer. You wrote that `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` "will delay the shutdown as long as it can". It means it still isn't reliable solution for launching big and long background processes, am I right?

Comment: Yes. If you expect the process to take longer than 90 seconds using a hangfire.io is the better option. Running it as a separate service is the best option, but may require code changes to make classes Serializeable. Running it in process works too but I don't know how much more time beyond 90 seconds it will give you. Could be 91 seconds, could be 4 days, I just don't know